# 1C - Bitrix CIBlockElement Update

Tags: php, битрикс, cms, 1с

Что я делаю не так ? Почему не обновляется пользовательское свойство ?
Согласно официальной документации вроде, вот код.

```
$el = new CIBlockElement;

$PROP = array();
$PROP[185] = "Белый";  // свойству с кодом 185 присваиваем значение "Белый"

$arLoadProductArray = Array(
  "MODIFIED_BY"    => $user_id,       // элемент изменен текущим пользователем
  "IBLOCK_SECTION" => false,          // элемент лежит в корне раздела
  "PROPERTY_VALUES"=> $PROP,
  "NAME"           => "Khalilov Срочное",
  "ACTIVE"         => "Y",            // активен
  "PREVIEW_TEXT"   => '',
  "DETAIL_TEXT"    => ''
  );

$PRODUCT_ID = 3866;  // изменяем элемент с кодом (ID)
$res = $el->Update($PRODUCT_ID, $arLoadProductArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Проверь правильность id элемента инфоблока
2. Проверь правильность id свойства инфоблока
3. Проверь активность элемента инфоблока и свойства

А вообще для задания свойств элементам я бы порекомендовал использовать 
SetPropertyValuesEx

Comment: уже 1000 раз проверил все вроде верно, и в конечном итоге воспользовался методом CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValues

Comment: "Метод возвращает true если изменение прошло успешно, при возникновении ошибки метод вернет false, а в свойстве LAST_ERROR объекта будет содержаться текст ошибки."
Можно попробовать посмотреть ошибку, если она имеется.